# Grunt project works when accessed from VSCode, but when deployed to Vercel, doesn't load JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, vercel

Sorry if the title is confusing. I'm learning Grunt in an online course, i've followed all the instructions, and the project works just fine when i go live through VSCode. But when i deploy it to Vercel, the Javascript files don't work. Both the JS and CSS files are linked in the HTML file the same way, yet only the CSS files work. [Also, the JS file and the folder it is on are greyed out on the VSCode explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbrrz.png)

The console says that there was a failure in loading the script, and the Vercel logs show 404 and 401 errors. I've searched about both these issues and couldn't find a solution to the exact problem i'm having. Here's the project: https://github.com/CinnAqua/gruntjs